# Telerik RadGrid Performance Too slow in Winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, telerik

i am loading more than 50000 Records in Rad grid win forms. how to optimize and makes the grid to loads fast (instant)?. is there option to load pagewise filter in telerik rad grid columns filter?.

```
 Me.cncFilesGridRad.MasterTemplate.AllowAddNewRow = False
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.MasterTemplate.AllowDeleteRow = False
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.MasterTemplate.ShowRowHeaderColumn = False
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.MasterTemplate.ShowHeaderCellButtons = False
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.UseScrollbarsInHierarchy = True
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.ShowGroupPanel = False
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = True
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.MasterTemplate.EnableSorting = True
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.MasterTemplate.EnableGrouping = False
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.EnableFiltering = True
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.ShowHeaderCellButtons = True

            Me.cncFilesGridRad.MasterTemplate.EnableFiltering = True
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.ShowFilteringRow = False
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.MasterTemplate.ShowFilterCellOperatorText = False
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.MasterTemplate.AllowCellContextMenu = False
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.EnableFastScrolling = True
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.BeginUpdate()
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.DataSource = GlobalVariables.CNCFilesCollection

            Me.cncFilesGridRad.AutoSizeRows = True

            Me.cncFilesGridRad.TableElement.RowHeight = 60
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.TableElement.FilterRowHeight = 40
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.GridViewElement.PagingPanelElement.NumericButtonsCount = 25
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.VirtualMode = True

            AddTemplateToGrid()

            Me.cncFilesGridRad.MasterTemplate.Templates(0).AllowAddNewRow = False
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.MasterTemplate.Templates(0).AllowDeleteRow = False
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.MasterTemplate.Templates(0).AllowEditRow = False


            For Each col As GridViewDataColumn In Me.cncFilesGridRad.Columns
                col.IsVisible = False
            Next

            For Each col As GridViewDataColumn In Me.cncFilesGridRad.MasterTemplate.Templates(0).Columns
                col.IsVisible = False
            Next

            'child row column
            column = Me.cncFilesGridRad.MasterTemplate.Templates(0).Columns("Name")
            column.HeaderText = "Name"
            column.IsVisible = True
            column.ReadOnly = True

            'parent rows
            checkColumn = New GridViewCheckBoxColumn()
            checkColumn.DataType = GetType(Integer)
            checkColumn.HeaderText = "Select"
            checkColumn.Name = "Select"
            checkColumn.IsVisible = True
            checkColumn.EditMode = EditMode.OnValueChange
            checkColumn.Width = 83
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.MasterTemplate.Columns.Add(checkColumn)
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.Columns.Move(checkColumn.Index, 0)

            commandColumn = New GridViewCommandColumn()
            commandColumn.Name = "EditColumn"
            commandColumn.UseDefaultText = True
            commandColumn.DefaultText = "Edit"
            commandColumn.FieldName = "Edit"
            commandColumn.Width = 50
            commandColumn.TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.MasterTemplate.Columns.Add(commandColumn)
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.Columns.Move(commandColumn.Index, 1)    

            descriptor.PropertyName = "Name"
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.Columns("Name").SortOrder = RadSortOrder.Ascending
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.MasterTemplate.SortDescriptors.Add(descriptor)



            Me.cncFilesGridRad.MasterTemplate.Templates(0).AutoSizeColumnsMode = Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill


            Me.cncFilesGridRad.CurrentRow = Nothing

            filterDescriptor.PropertyName = "Name"
            filterDescriptor.[Operator] = FilterOperator.StartsWith
            filterDescriptor.IsFilterEditor = True
            Me.cncFilesGridRad.Columns("Name").FilterDescriptor = filterDescriptor
```

how to improve the rad grid performance while loading more Records?

Comment: 50000 records is too much for a grid. Load data paged. Take a look at [Paging Overview](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/paging/overview) or [Emulating Paging with RadGridView for WinForms and LINQ with 1 million records](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/emulating-paging-with-radgridview-for-winforms-and-linq-with-1-million-records)

Comment: I recommend that you examine the article below for useful tips about how to optimize RadGrid performance: 
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-viewstate-reduction-techniques.html

Comment: Load the records as the page moves, i.e. one page can have 100 records, when we click second page, it will have another 100 records.. that will improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

Load the records as the page moves, i.e. one page can have `100` records, when we click second page, it will have another `100` records.. that will *improve performance*.

Comment: how to load the record as pagewise radgrid winforms ? could You share the example?

Comment: You can filter data in your SQL query or filter DefaultView of DataTable object and bind it to the RadGridView. Also you can bind a DataTable object to a BindingSource object, setup its Filter property and then bind to RadGridView.

Answer (score 0):

What you should be looking at is the **Pagination** capability. And Telerik's [GridView](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/overview) control supports this feature naturally.

> The data layer of RadGridView now supports pagination of data natively. You can still bind RadGridView to the same data providers as before with the addition of the paging option. There is a number of features, which will allow you to easily configure and manage the paging of the data.

Please refer to the following links for more details on how paging works.

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/paging/overview#paging-overview

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/paging/paging-panel

http://www.telerik.com/videos/winforms/radgridview-for-winforms-webinar